# Integrating Facebook calender to Wordpress

Tags: facebook, events, the-events-calendar

i have a requirement, it goes like this

I have a signup, login front-end page for users and visitors. Users can also register themselves with facebook login id. For users who have logged in via Facebook, birthdays and events of their friends as well as his events will be pulled out from Facebook and will be added to the website custom event calendar. The user’s events will be pulled out from facebook every time he/she logs in.

Can this be achieved .... kindly suggest me and help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is very broad. Please narrow down your question, and show us what you have tried already.

Comment: And if you need help merging your new account into the old one, see [this help page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: ALso looking for plugin to show not google but facebook event thrue facebook or google imported plugin